# Fixed week height in fullcalendar month view

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm attempting to make a fullcalendar where each week row in the month view is always the same height, regardless of how many weeks are showing for this month.  The height of the calendar itself will change depending on how many weeks are in the month, but each row is always the same height.

I know an easy way to do this would be to always show 6 weeks per month, but unfortunately that's not an option for this project.  I know I could also override the css to give the rows a fixed height with "!important", but that's basically a hack.  So is there any built-in way to accomplish this, or will I basically just have to hack it?  Thanks.

Comment: What version of fullcalendar are you using?

Comment: You will need to clarify. In month view, the weeks are all the same height already. See the example on http://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: I'm using the latest (v2.2.6).  The example on fullcalendar.io has it fixed to 6 weeks, but if it were setup to have a variable number of weeks then the weeks would be different heights when you went between months with 5 or 6 weeks.